# wx python panel.Destroy() causes python 2 crash

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I've been designing a python program using wx designed to basicly copy files from one directory to another. Basically.
The problem is, when from my main screen, you click go, the hole thing just up and crashes. WITH NO ERROR!
I have posted code snippets below, and hopefully someone can help me with this.

Code snippet one, this snipper shows the window being set up:

```
class Mywin(wx.Frame): 
 def __init__(self, parent, title): 
 global frame
  global panel
  frame=self;
  super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (350,250))
  panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, style= wx.WANTS_CHARS)
  self.panel=panel
  vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
  hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
  l1 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Backup source") 
  panel.SetBackgroundColour("black")
  hbox1.Add(l1, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL,5) 
  self.t1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
  hbox1.Add(self.t1,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL,5) 
  vbox.Add(hbox1) 
  browse1 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Browse")
  browse1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.browsebutton1)
  hbox1.Add(browse1,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL,5) 
  vbox.Add(hbox1)
  hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
  l2 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Backup destination") 
  hbox2.Add(l2, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL,5) 
  self.t2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
  hbox2.Add(self.t2,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL,5) 
  browse2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Browse")
  browse2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.browsebutton2)
  hbox2.Add(browse2,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL,5) 
  vbox.Add(hbox2)
  hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
  sel=wx.CheckBox(panel, label = 'write to log file')
  self.cb1 = sel
  sel2=wx.CheckBox(panel, label = 'delete files found in destination that are not found in source?')
  self.cb2 = sel2
  hbox3.Add(sel,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL,5) 
  hbox3.Add(sel2,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL,5) 
  vbox.Add(hbox3)
  gobutton = wx.Button(panel, -1, "go!")
  gobutton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.go)
  vbox.Add(gobutton)
  panel.SetSizer(vbox)
  Publisher.subscribe(self.updatestuff, "update")
  self.Center()
  self.Show();
  self.Fit()
```

Code snippet two, from the go button:

```
 def go(self, again):
  sourcepath=os.path.realpath(self.t1.GetValue())
  print 'got source'
  destpath=os.path.realpath(self.t2.GetValue())
  print 'got source'
  if(os.path.exists(sourcepath)==False):
   wx.MessageBox("Source path not valid", 'error!', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
   return;
  if(os.path.exists(destpath)==False):
   wx.MessageBox("Destination path not valid", 'error!', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
   return;
  if(sourcepath==destpath):
   wx.MessageBox("The source and destination path may not be the same.", 'error!', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
   return;
  print 'checked source and dest valid'
  self.backup(sourcepath, destpath, self.cb1.GetValue(), self.cb2.GetValue())
```

code snippet 3, where it crashes:

```
 def backup(self, source, dest, log, deletee):
  print 'readying screen'
  global frame
  self=frame
  global panel
 global dolog
  global dodel
  global starttime
  starttime=time.time()
  print 'got time set crrectly'
  dolog=log
  print 'set logging';
  self.panel.Destroy();
```

It gets as far as setting up log, before the wx window freezes[not responding], and then python2.exe comes as stopped working, and windows will search for a solution.
I've tried reinstalling wx python, and that did not fix it.
I also tried using panel as a global variable, but that produced the same error.
Any help on this matter would be appreciated, and if anyone has any glew to stick my hair back on that is also helpful, because I've pulled it all out! :)
Thanks

Comment: What do you expect with `self=frame`? Once `self` is created you should not modify it.

Comment: EVEN REMOVING THAT LINE, THE PROBLEM STAYS THE SAME